# Cannot read property 'interceptors' of undefined

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, angular-http-interceptors, angularjs-injector

my app is connecting to a nodejs backend for authentication, the factory and config are as follow

```
angular.module('app.services', [])
.factory('AuthInterceptor', [function($rootScope, $q, AUTH_EVENTS) {
  return {
    responseError: function(response) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast({
        401: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,
      }[response.status], response);
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
}])
.service('AuthService', [function($q, $http, API_ENDPOINT) { 
// some methods
])}
.config([function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
}]);
```

the starting page is a login page but I face a blank page with the error in console

```
 ionic.bundle.js:8900 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.services due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'interceptors' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8100/js/services.js:94:16
```

where line 94:16 in services,js is: `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');`

how can I solve it

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to provide the dependency string in the call to `config`:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
}]);
```